# Работа с сертификатами в PHP

Tags: php, openssl

День добрый, люди добрые!
Первый раз приходится работать с сертификатами в PHP.
Задача у меня такое: авторизацию через сертификаты, на сайте конечно же.

Сертификат в закрытом виде , то есть расширение в виде `*.p12`.

Как я понял это `#PKCS12 =  cer+private_key`.
В сети есть примеры, как прочитать с помощью библиотеки open SSL(openssl_pkcs12_read).
Но оно выдает ошибку :

```
error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:not enough data
```

Сам код выглядит так:

```
<?php
    print 'OpenSSl Certificate Test!';

    $filename = 'rai.p12';
    $password = '123456';
    $results = array();
    $worked = openssl_pkcs12_read($filename, $results, $password);
    if($worked) {
    echo '<pre>', print_r($results, true), '</pre>';
    } else {
        echo openssl_error_string();
    }
?>
```

PS: хотелось бы узнать подробнее, как работают сертификаты , как пользоваться с функциями `openssl`, буду рад  к любым советам/комментам/ссылкам.

Answer (score 2):

я ни разу не работал с сертификатами, но мне кажется, что проблема вот в чем:

в функцию openssl_pkcs12_read() Вы передаете путой массив $results, поэтому она и не срабатывает и плюется ошибками. Согласно [мануалу](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-pkcs12-read.php) это обязательный параметр и он не должен быть пустым.

Если это не так, то прошу прощения =)

Comment: чуть подправлю ) в массив $results openssl заносить данные, которые прочитал с сертификата, в результате мы получим данные с ключа, через этот массив...

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, чуток не понял, можете код написать?

Comment: @mountpoint, я не описываю решение. Пишу ,просто как я понял роль #results-a, прочитав ман. А код, оно же в ТЗ. 
Пока еще не смог считывать с *.p12 ключа.